# Navegando entre o conteudo de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Estudando sobre array eu entendi que  `array = document.querySelectorAll(".nomeClasse")` retorna um array que contem cada elemento que usa essa classe. Mas ainda não ficou claro para mim como você acessa os elementos dentro do array criado.

```
<tbody id="tableTask">
        <tr class="task">
            <td class="infoIndice">1</td>
            <td class="infoTask">Limpar Cozinha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="task">
            <td class="infoIndice">1</td>
            <td class="infoTask">Recolher Cocô do Cachorro</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Nesse exemplo eu uso `task = document.querySelectorAll(".task")` e recebo um array com 2 elementos que são os 2 `<tr>` que usam a classe `task`.

Como, a partir dai, eu tenho acesso ao segundo `td`? (Recolher Cocô do Cachorro)

Se eu quiser mudar o conteudo dessa `td`por exemplo. existe alguma especie de "`task[1].td(infoTask).innerHTML = "lavar a roupa";`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deste resposta à tua pergunta... `task[1]` é uma maneira correta de acessar o segundo elemento da array. Repara que `querySelectorAll` retorna uma coleção, mais ou menos uma array. Depois, para responder à tua segunda pergunta podes usar `children[1]` para aceder ao segundo `td` ou `.querySelector('.infoTask')`.

Exemplo:

```js
const tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
tasks[1].querySelector('.infoTask').innerText = 'Ir às compras';
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tableTask">
    <tr class="task">
      <td class="infoIndice">1</td>
      <td class="infoTask">Limpar Cozinha</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="task">
      <td class="infoIndice">2</td>
      <td class="infoTask">Lavar a roupa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Depois de algum tempo eu percebi que podia usar o `querySelectorAll` com o `task`assim como fazemos com `document`. É algo trivial mas eu começei meus estudos a pouco tempo e é tanta informação que demora um pouco para o cérebro digerir e fazer essas ligações de forma automática.

Mas foi bom ter feito a pergunta pois eu não sabia do método de usar `children[x]`. Obrigado pela resposta, eu estava prestres a responder minha própria pergunta quando você responderu ela. :)

Comment: @DanielCarvalhodeOliveira fico contente de ter ajudado :)